# error: unable to find valid values for all labels after 1003 passes; stalled for 1001, giving up

Tags: string, assembly, x86-64, nasm

I am new to NASM coding, was trying string operations but keep receiving the error:

> unable to find valid values for all labels after 1003 passes; stalled for 1001, giving up.

Tried all methods on internet but couldn't find any solution.

```
%macro scall 4          
    mov rax,%1
    mov rdi,%2
    mov rsi,%3
    mov rdx,%4
    syscall         ;call the kernel           
%endmacro

%macro quit 0
    mov rax,60 
    mov rdi,0 
    syscall

%endmacro

section .data
    m1 db 10d,13d,"Enter the String",10d
    l1 equ $-m1
    m2 db 10d,13d,"Length of string",10d,13d
    l2 equ $-m2
    m3 db 10d,13d,"Reversed String",10d,13d
    l3 equ $-m3
    m4 db 10d,13d,""
    l4 equ $-m4
    m5 db 10d,13d, "1.Enter the String "
    l5 equ $-l5
    m6 db 10d,13d, "2.Length of String "
    l6 equ $-l6
    m7 db 10d,13d, "3.Reverse of String"
    l7 equ $-l7
    m8 db 10d,13d, "4.exit"
    l8 equ $-l8
        
section .bss
    string resb 50
    string2 resb 50
    length resb 16
    answer resb 16
    choice resb 8
        
section .text
    global _start
_start:
scall 1,1,m4,l4

menu: 
    scall 1,1,m5,l5
    scall 1,1,m6,l6
    scall 1,1,m7,l7
    scall 1,1,m8,l8
    scall 0,0,choice,2
    
case1:
cmp choice,31h
je enterstring

case2:

cmp choice,32h
je len

case3:

cmp choice,33h
je rev

case4:

cmp choice,34h
je exit
    
    scall 1,1,m4,l4
    
enterstring:
    scall 1,1,m4,l4
    scall 1,1,m1,l1
    scall 0,0,string,50
    jmp menu
    
len:
    mov [length],rax

    scall 1,1,m2,l2
    mov rax,[length]
    call display            ;call  display procedure
    jmp menu
    
rev:
    scall 1,1,m3,l3
    call reverse
    jmp menu

exit:
quit

;*******DISPLAY LENGTH ***********       
display:                        ;hex to ascii-hex
    mov rbp,answer
    mov rcx,2

loop1:
    rol al,04
    mov dl,al 
    and dl,0Fh 
    cmp dl,09h
    jbe loop2
    add dl,07h 
loop2:
    add dl,30h 
    mov [rbp],rdx 
    inc rbp
    dec rcx
    jnz loop1 
scall 1,1,answer,6 
ret

;****** DISPLAY REVERSE STRING*******
reverse:
    mov rsi,string     ; point rsi to first byte of original srting
    mov rdi,string2    ; point rdi to first byte of reversed string 
    mov rcx,[length]   ; counter 
    add rsi,rcx        ; point rsi to next byte after original string 
    dec rsi            ; now rsi points to last byte
next:
    mov rax,[rsi]       ;move character to al 
    mov [rdi],rax       ;Copy character to string2
    dec rsi
    inc rdi
    loop next
scall 1,1,string2,50
ret
```

This is the NASM error I get everytime in this code:

> error: Can't find valid values for all labels after 1000 passes, giving up.
> error: Possible causes: recursive EQUs, macro abuse.

Comment: Separate from whatever's causing this this build error, it doesn't normally make sense to use `10d,13d` `\n\r` reversed-DOS line-endings in a program using Linux system calls.  Linux's line separator is just `\n`, i.e. `0xa` aka `10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`l5 equ $-l5` should be `l5 equ $-m5`, and similarly for others where you're subtracting lengths from positions instead of subtracting two positions.

Also, that definition alone is itself recursive (`l5 = stuff  - itself`), so that's a problem.

---

That's why you're getting *this* error; once fixed then NASM is able to get to other errors and tell you about them, but those have line numbers so you can find which line is the problem.  (e.g. an attempt to `cmp choice, 31h`, where `choice` is a symbol name, i.e. address.  `cmp` doesn't work with two immediates, and that's not what you want anyway.  Use `default rel` and `cmp byte [choice], 31h`, probably.)